# How to print \[ and \] to terminal from python?

Tags: python, bash, terminal, ansi-colors, color-codes

I am able to print ANSI color codes from python to the terminal using code such as `print "\033[31m red text \033[0m"`, which prints "red text" in red.

However, when wrapping text, the terminal still counts the invisible control characters, so the text wraps incorrectly, acting as if the line is longer than it actually is. Reverse-i-search also acts weird, displaying text that does not match up with what is actually under the cursor.

The following link (and others)
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Regular_user_2 seems to indicate that I need to wrap colors codes in `\[` and `\]` so that terminal can place the cursor correctly on the screen. However, when I `print "\[\033[31m\]"` in python, the brackets show up on the screen.

**How can I send the `\[` and `\]` control characters to terminal from python?**

*(I've found that color libraries, such as `colored`, have the same problem)*

Comment: `\[` and `\]` are only interpreted (and useful) within the value of the various `PS?` variables in `bash`. In other contexts, you are responsible for identifying and accounting for invisible characters printed to the terminal.

Comment: @chepner - That happens to be exactly what I'm using it for, a tool like hg-prompt for customizing the bash prompt easily.

Comment: Then you just want to pass those characters literally. Displaying them doesn't do anything special; it's `bash` when calculating the length of the value of `PS1` that does not include anything between them in its count.

Comment: @chepner - Thanks! This solved my problem. I had previously tried this, but tested the script in terminal and saw the `\[`, and assumed it did not work. But when I use the script in my $PS1, it works great.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use [ ] around your color codes.
just create variables such as below.

```
red = '\033[31m'
print red
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Bash prompt vs in Python:

- `\[` == `'\001'`
- `\]` == `'\002'`

[source](https://superuser.com/a/301355/443564)

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment by @chepner - 
My problem involved modifying the `PS1` variable in terminal to get a colored prompt.

Directly printing `\[` and `\]` from python showed those characters on the screen, but when passed to `PS1`, the characters were invisible and the colored text displayed correctly and wrapped correctly on the screen.